# Role of Pettis measurability theorem in the construction of the Bochner integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

I am reading a brief introduction to Bochner integral, and before introducing it, it is proved the Pettis measurability theorem, which says that a function $f:A \to B$ (with $A$ a measure space with $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ and $B$ a Banach space) is strongly $\mu$-measurable (that is that there is a sequence of simple functions which converges pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere) iff its image is almost fully contained in a separable closed subspace of $B$ and $\Lambda \circ f$ is measurable $\forall \Lambda \in \mathcal{L}(A,\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is considered to have borelians as measurable subsets. There is a third equivalence, in fact, but I don't think it is important for my question.

For standard Lebesgue integrals, there is a canonical way to construct a sequence of simple functions that tends to $f$ almost everywhere, but this construction uses the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. With Banach spaces, I suppose that Pettis theorem helps by giving an equivalent condition, given that this construction is not possible (or at least I wouldn't know how to do that). Once you have a strongly $\mu$-measurable function, the other properties should follow like the Lebesgue case. For instance, a function $f$ is Bochner integrable iff its norm is integrable and its integral is finite (and this gives us a useful criterion for Bochner integrability, because I know how to integrate $||f||:A \to \mathbb{R}$ ).

This criterion is very useful and the proof works if you know that $||f||$ is strongly $\mu$-measurable, and this is indeed a corollary of Pettis measurability theorem.

I am wondering though: is this the only way in which Pettis theorem helps in the construction of the integral? I see that it is useful in other ways, but it looks like it is used only to prove the strong $\mu$-measurability of $||f||$.

Comment: I just know the definition of being $\mu$-measurable in this strongest sense, I didn't knew that exists some other definition of $\mu$-measurability. Where you read this?

Comment: @Masacaroso what is your definition? I will try to find the pdf on internet, I only have a paper copy of it

Comment: Here it is: https://ocw.tudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/Lecture01_01.pdf

Comment: I have the definition of the book *Analysis III* of Amann and Escher, it says that a function is $\mu$-measurable if there is a sequence of $\mu$-simple functions that converges point-wise almost everywhere to $f$. A $\mu$-simple function is a function who image set is finite, it maps a finite number of measurable sets $A_j$ of finite measure to some values $x_j$

Comment: however the previous book just stay it theory on functions $f:X\to E$ where $X$ is a $\mu$-measurable $\sigma$-finite space and $E$ is a Banach space. Perhaps for a more general approach then there are more definitions of measurability

Comment: We have the same definition, then. What I was wondering is the utility of Pettis theorem in this construction, in giving an easy criterion for integrability

Comment: It looks like it is used for proving $||f||$ is strongly $\mu$-measurable, and then this fact is enough for proving a quite simple criterion, but I was wondering if that theorem could be used in a more direct way